# Reader doesn't seem to be installed in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have installed TensorFlow through pip for python 2.7.

I am trying to run some example RNN models, one of which requires the import of reader.

```
from tensorflow.models.rnn.ptb import reader

-> I get a no module reader found.
```

After reading a bit, I tried a popular suggestions:

```
import reader

-> no module reader found.
```

I ran:

```
import inspect
>>> print inspect.getfile(reader)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'reader' is not defined
```

Isn't reader supposed to be part of tensorflow? How can I install this module?

I need it because in the code I am trying to run, it includes commands like this:

```
def gen_epochs(n, num_steps, batch_size):
    for i in range(n):
        yield reader.ptb_iterator(data, batch_size, num_steps)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried installing tensorflow for python3, but same issue.

So I just put this reader.py file in my main folder: http://programtalk.com/vs2/?source=python/7331/tensorflow_with_latest_papers/reader.py and that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the reader from github:
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/models/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/reader.py

and add the file path and module to your python project:

```
import os

import sys

scriptpath = "/My/Path/To/Module/File/" 

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(scriptpath))

import reader
```

2. Otherwise, A file can be read using:

   from tensorflow import read_file

instead of:

```
from tensorflow.models.rnn.ptb import reader
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `reader.py` is part of http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow, but it's included in http://github.com/tensorflow/models. It's used in  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb and there's a commit message 3 months ago for `reader.py` that says "Moving example models from github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow to github.com/tensorflow/models".

In the example code `ptb_word_lm.py` of the tutorials/rnn/ptb, there's a `import reader` and I'm able to run `ptb_word_lm.py` successfully.

Comment: That makes sense, only that I am running a different tutorial that didn't mention that (don't have the models folder here). But by copying reader it worked.